# Should I use .map() to restructure my data from an HttpClient request?

Tags: angular, geojson

My data is coming in from my rest api as

```
{[{"location":1,"latitude":"00.000","longitude":"000.000"}, 
  {"location":2,"latitude":"00.000","longitude":"000.000"}]}
```

But I would like to have it in the form

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {"type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[00.0000,00.00000]
                },
    "properties":{
        "location":1
                  }
  },
   {"type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[00.00000,-00.0000]
                },
    "properties":{
        "location":2
                  }
]}
```

So I would need to add the type : featurecollection and the features:[] 
before I even began iterating through the object...

Then I would need to add the geometry and properties objects.  Can I do all of this in a model first?

I really don't even know where to begin. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your initial data isn't valid JSON. Also, which version of RXJS are you using?

Comment: I just hand wrote that one.  I am using RXJS6 but I can use the compat if I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the real data is simply the array, what you've posted is not something valid.

You can simply map the array to the desired output like below

```js
const arr = [{
    "location": 1,
    "latitude": "00.000",
    "longitude": "000.000"
  },
  {
    "location": 2,
    "latitude": "00.000",
    "longitude": "000.000"
  }
];

const res = {
  type: 'Feature Collection',
  features: arr.map(e => ({
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [e.latitude, e.longitude]
    },
    "properties": {
      "location": e.location
    }
  }))
};

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Will try this out. Thank you.  But yes when I console logged the data with JSON.stringify it gave me the array.  I messed up adding the {} outside of it. Also if I were doing this in Angular, would I just set these up in the completed portion of the subscribe function? That was I have all of my data already?  I see most people do the httpClient.get('').pipe(map (data) => return something).subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```js
const features = data.map(value => {
    const { location, latitude, longitude } = value;
    return {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [ latitude, longitude ],
            properties: {
                location
            }
        }
    }
});

const obj = { type: "FeatureCollection", features };
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If I were doing this in Angular, would I just set these up in the completed portion of the subscribe function? That way I have all of my data already? I see most people do the httpClient.get('').pipe(map (data) => return something).subscribe

Comment: Well yeah, but you could cast to a custom object (model) to make your code cleaner, eg: `new FeatureCollection(data)` and inside that model you can perform the necessary transformations